# Can I build tensorflow without android and without tensorboard?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard, bazel

I am trying to build tensorflow in a system that doesn't have internet access.  I've downloaded the dependencies listed in tensorflow/workspace.bzl externally.  But now the configure is trying to fetch a bunch of dependencies in the WORKSPACE file.  They all look like UI packages needed for tensorboard.

Is there a way I can edit the configure to skip over these packages since I wont be needing the tensorboard or android code?

Answer (score 1):

I tried a bunch of ways to remove the external dependencies used in tensorboard, all of which broke the build since I am not experienced with bazel.

But! here is what I found that did work:

- Comment out all build directives for tensorboard and android in ./tensorflow/BUILD
- Comment out all build directives for tensorboard in ./tensorflow/tensorboard/BUILD
- Delete bower build file: ./tensorflow/tensorboard/bower/BUILD.  (Despite commenting tensorboard from the higher level BUILD files, bower just kept wanting to compile)

Here is the semi-tedious part if you dont have internet access:

- Manually download required dependencies in ./tensorflow/workspace.bzl from external system and transfer into local system
- Then update ./tensorflow/workspace.bzl urls to file path in system